# SetWindowsHookEx fails to inject

Tags: c++, dll-injection, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to intercept messages sent to a window running in another process, so that I can react to a few of them.

The injecting application is an x86 WPF application that calls this method via p/invoke.  I pass the handle to a window in another x86 process.

```
extern "C" BOOL INJ_API ::InterceptMessages(HWND hWnd)
{
    if (!WM_MY_INJECT)
    {
        WM_MY_INJECT = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("WM_MY_INJECT"));
    }

    // Get the ID of the thread running the window.
    DWORD ThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL);

    // Set the hook
    hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, HookProc, hinstDLL, ThreadId);

    // hhk is non-zero, so the hook is set up

    // This will block until the WM_MY_INJECT message is processed, the hook is unhooked, and we are done injecting the application.
    LRESULT result = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_MY_INJECT, NULL, NULL);

    return TRUE;
}
```

I know that the message is being sent, because result is the correct value.  But the DLL is never loaded by the other process, and the message is called without my hook intercepting it.

Comment: Are you sure you have the privilege to inject?

Comment: I'm running 64-bit Windows 7 without UAC... Both applications are run by the same user in the same desktop, so as far as I know, I should have permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WH_GETMESSAGE` is for hooking messages that are retreived from a message queue by `GetMessage()` or `PeekMessage()`.  Messages sent with `SendMessage()` do not go through those functions, and thus will not trigger a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook.  You need to either use `PostMessage()` instead of `SendMessage()`,  or use a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` or `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` hook instead of a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also tried the same code with WH_CALLWNDPROC, and that had the exact same problem.

Comment: calling `PeekMessage()`, rather than `SendMessage()` solved my issue.